# How to create my own custom search bar Using Algolia Api's. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, frontend, algolia

I want to create a custom **search bar** in which I can search **Orders** using Algolia Api's. I know that there is an Algolia extension which is used for to search products but How can I use Algolia Api's to sync with my Media n search Products?? I'm totally blind in this scenario Please just show me the way that how to start with **Algolia Api's**. Thanks